# MySQL Store Procedure with Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, stored-procedures

I would like to know, **in general**, performance comparison executing a stored procedure that execute a statement with a syntax as

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE query VARCHAR(5000);
    SET @query = " <SQL CODE>";

    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

END
```

or executing directly AS

```
BEGIN

    <SQL CODE>;

END
```

in my case i must use first case because i want to set a input parameter to set custom LIMIT. And I wondered if, in general, there could be some performance degradation.

MySQL Information

- protocol_version 10
- version  5.0.95
- version_bdb  Sleepycat Software: Berkeley DB 4.1.24: (December 16, 2011)
- version_comment  Source
- distribution version_compile_machine x86_64
- version_compile_os   redhat-linux-gnu

Comment: protocol_version 10
version 5.0.95
version_bdb Sleepycat Software: Berkeley DB 4.1.24: (December 16, 2011)
version_comment Source distribution
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os redhat-linux-gnu

Comment: I just wanted to say that you could use variables in LIMIT clause directly in MySQL 5.5. From the documentation: Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL 5.5.6.

Comment: cool i'll do it! but in general what you think about performance beetween statement execution or sql execution?

Comment: Take a look at this page - http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/02/mysql-prepared-statements/

Comment: as with all things there are pros and cons